# Delete images if the user is leaving the component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, prompt

I have form with a drag and drop component where I can upload images, after this I send these pictures with axios to my backend and save it on server side and then re-render it in a preview mode. My problem is, that if a user uploads some pictures and after that he switches to another page without submitting the form the added pictures are staying on my server side for no reason.

So the question: I want to check inside my component if a user is leaving, show a prompt and if he clicks on the OK button I want to delete all the added pictures from my backend before leaving. How can I detect this?

My simplified snippet:

```
function MyComp(props) {
     const [Images,setImages] = useState([]) // in this array I store the recieved image's URL
     const [isBlocking,setIsBlocking] = useState(true) // used for prompt

 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setIsBlocking(false)
      }


 return(
        <Grid container className={classes.mainGrid} direction="row" spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={4} xl={4}> 
            
            <Prompt when={isBlocking} message="There are unsaved datas. Are you sure you want to leave?"/>
            
            <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            ... somecode
       </Grid>
      </Grid>
    )
}
export default MyComp
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside React Function Component you can call the prompt when the user is trying to leave , i.e when the component is unmounting

In Class Component of React you can use React componentWillUnmount() and in Function Component You can use useEffect cleanup function

Code for Function Component

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Home(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    return function cleanup() {
      alert("unmounting");
     //call api and execute your code here
    };
  }, []);

  return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/home">
          On Click I will unmount this component and go to /home
        </Link>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Code for Class Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
export default class Test extends Component {
  componentWillUnmount() {
    alert('unmounting component');
    //call your code here
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to='/home'>
          On Click I will unmount this component and go to /home
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can check this codesandbox if you want any ref

[image: Edit adoring-sun-dwnde]

Comment: use can add another useEffect without any params passed to it , it will behave the same as componentWillUnmount

Comment: Indeed it works and can detect the page leaving, but using the useEffect without adding the Images as dependency results that at the cleanup function my Images array is empty, however in state has values. Do you have any idea how to solve it this problem? Thank you again :)

Comment: The useEffect without any params will run only once  , you need to pass the image state as params so that it will be called every time data array changes and then handle component unmount seperately , if you could share another question with code or sandbox , I could help you better

Comment: Actually I asked it and I recieved a solving too. Thank you for everything/

Answer (score 0):

When you leave the page, the component method `componentWillUnmount()` fires. I don't recall how this behaves if you were to simply close the browser window as opposed to just navigating away, nor do I recall how you can escape it and stay on the component, but that should at least be a good starting point for you. Obviously you'd have to do a class extending React.Component for this one instead of a straight function.